# Generate what a GRUB2 kernel line would look like

Tags: kernel, rhel, grub2

In GRUB 0.97 we were able to see what the kernel line/options would look like by just viewing `/boot/grub/grub.conf`.

Now the only way I know how to check the next boot kernel options/kernel version is by rebooting and waiting until the new GRUB2 menu generates.

How can I view kernel options/version that will be loaded in GRUB2 prior to rebooting?

Would it be possible to generate an "example" GRUB menu prior to reboot so we can see what it would look like without having to piece together configuration files?

Comment: Did you checkout /boot/grub2/grub.cfg file?

Comment: @alpertek as far as I am aware the /boot/grub2/grub.cfg file only tells grub _how_ to build the grub configuration. It doesn't give me a sample or an example of what the output would look like.

Comment: That may help: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62861/how-to-figure-out-grub2s-menu-output

Comment: @alpertek whoa, that looks a bit cumbersome :P It looks like its asking to pass the filesystem through a VM to see what grub looks like on the filesystem that is being passed through. This is not overly convenient, and does work. But I'm looking for something a bit easier/repeatable so that I can write instructions/make a script around it. Thanks tho!